# Header-bg div 100% isnt really 100%

Tags: html, css

I got this problem trying to get the header-bg div to always be the full browser width.

I have a background image with some clouds and when I use ctrl+scroll the image stays the original width and stays left aligned. At original page view the bg is perfect 100% width, but I want it to be perfect with al screen widths. Is this even possible or am I wrong?

Heres the code:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;} 


#header-bg {
    background-image:url(images/header/header-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    height:402px;}

<div id="header-bg">
<div id="header">
<div id="navigation">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Background images aren't scaled by default although there are some hacks to make it work. See [this link](http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the background image cannot resize. The [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) property has to be used to get your background to fill the whole DIV:

```
#header-bg {
     background-image: url(images/header/header-bg.jpg);  

    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /*Other CSS*/
}
```

This CSS feature is supported by:

- Firefox 3.6+
- Opera 9.5+
- Chrome 1+
- Safari 3+
- Internet Explorer 9+

If you cannot use this property, your only remaining option is using a `<img>` element.
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hf79s/**

```
<style>
#header-bg{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#header-bg-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id="header-bg">
    <img src="images/header/header-bg.jpg" id="header-bg-img" />
</div>
```

Comment: F*ckin awsome! Thanks men, this got the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the background image extra wide, so it will fill big screens too. The only downside is that smaller screens won't see the entire image, but when it is only decorative clouds, it should be fine.

The other solution is background-size. But this has the disadvantage that the background will either be scale disproportionately, or the bottom of the image is clipped. Also older IE versions don't support it.